# Pandas to_datetime unexpected UTC return

Tags: python, pandas, utc, string-to-datetime

I am trying to set time index to pandas DataFrame using pandas.to_datetime function, but the outcome datetime is UTC when converting seconds, and while it is not requested :

```
import pandas
import datetime,time

datetime1 = '2017-03-30T12-00-00'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")
s = time.mktime(d.timetuple())

print pandas.to_datetime(datetime1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")
print pandas.to_datetime(s, unit='s')
```

Get two different results, although utc option of pandas.to_datetime is not used in both cases.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`time.mktime()` does not return UTC by default, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) for `time.mktime()`:

*Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple [...] which expresses the time in local time, not UTC.*

Comment: Yes, `time.mktime()` return local time. But once in `pandas.to_datetime`, the pandas outcome is UTC.

Comment: My mistake was in `mktime` understanding, I should have used `calendar.timegm` : `s = calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())`